# php-fpm and Nginx dynamic environment variable

Tags: linux, php, bash, php-fpm, environment-variables

[FPM configration](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#clear-env) stats that you can retrieve variables from your current environment. However, on ubuntu using Nginx and PHP-FPM, I can not find a way to retrieve the variable value from the environment **without hard coding it in the php-fpm.conf or nginx fcgi params**.

Is there a way to get the environment variable from /etc/environment or /etc/bash.bashrc?

For ex:

```
clear_env = no
ENV[SECRET_TOKEN] = $SECRET_TOKEN
```

I think the main problem is not being able to modify the env vars for www-data. As `>sudo -H -u www-data bash -c "env"` does not include `SECRET_TOKEN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way is to [add the env vars manually](http://l33t.peopleperhour.com/2014/03/13/setting-environment-variables-in-php-fpm-when-using-docker-links/).

I modified the code a bit

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$confFile = '/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params';

// Update the fpm configuration to make the environment variables available
// NOTE: ONLY in the CLI will $_SERVER have environment variables in it.
$content = file_get_contents($confFile);
$line = false;
foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $val) {
    if (strstr($name, 'SYMFONY') !== false) {
        $line = "fastcgi_param {$name} {$val};\n";
        # Either Add or Reset the variable
        if (strstr($content, $name) !== false) {
            $content = preg_replace('/fastcgi_param[\s\t]+'.$name.'\][\s\t]+.*?\n/', $line, $content);
            echo "MODIFIED {$name}\n";
        } else {
            $content .= "\n{$line}";
            echo "ADDED    {$name}\n";
        }
    }
}
if ($line) {
    file_put_contents($confFile, $content);
}
```